# transverse acceleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration

Can someone define the **transverse acceleration** with an example and what is the difference between the **transverse acceleration** and the **tangential acceleration** , if it mentioned in a textbook i will be satisfied ?!

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone define the **transverse acceleration**

The word "transverse" has its usual meaning. And here likely means perpendicular to the direction of motion.

> with an example

So, for example, in *circular* motion, the transverse acceleration would be the *radial* component of acceleration.

> and what is ... the **tangential acceleration**

The word "tangential" here also has its usual meaning. It means along the direction of the tangent line. So, for example, in *circular* motion, the tangential acceleration would be the component of acceleration in the direction of the motion (along the circle).

Comment: well actually according to my textbook both of the tangential and the transverse acceleration being tanget to the circualr motion so this is why i'm confused , if is there any textbook that you recommend i'll be gratefull for you ...

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Physics-Robert-Resnick/dp/1119801141/